# Developing a new Convolution Neural Network from scratch

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I like to develop a new convolution neural network from scratch and the network is shown at the bottom (only main trunk without data input and classifier).

For that, I need a pretrained model and here are few options [tutorial 1](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/) and [tutorial 2](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/transfer-learning-the-art-of-fine-tuning-a-pre-trained-model/). I have 1200 training images.
I am wondering what would be the better approach for the following two options.

1. Augment 1200 images to become 22,000 images. I need to augment around 18 images from 1 image. Then train the network with no initialization.
2. Train the network with Images from VOC2007 and VOC2012. There are 20000 images for both training and test. For that, I will train the model with fully connected layer with 1000 outputs, then leave fc layer in transfer learning.

What would be better?

```
     layer {
      name: "conv1"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "data"
      top: "conv1"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
        decay_mult: 1.0
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
        decay_mult: 0.0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 6
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0.0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "relu1"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv1"
      top: "conv1"
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv2"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "conv1"
      top: "conv2"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
        decay_mult: 1.0
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
        decay_mult: 0.0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 6
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0.0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "relu2"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv2"
      top: "conv2"
    }
    layer {
      name: "pool2"
      type: "Pooling"
      bottom: "conv2"
      top: "pool1"
      pooling_param {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 3
        stride: 3
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv3"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "pool2"
      top: "conv3"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
        decay_mult: 1.0
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
        decay_mult: 0.0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 16
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0.0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "relu3"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv3"
      top: "conv3"
    }
    layer {
      name: "pool3"
      type: "Pooling"
      bottom: "conv3"
      top: "pool3"
      pooling_param {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 2
        stride: 2
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv4"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "pool3"
      top: "conv4"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
        decay_mult: 1.0
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
        decay_mult: 0.0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 32
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0.0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "relu4"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv4"
      top: "conv4"
    }
    layer {
      name: "pool4"
      type: "Pooling"
      bottom: "conv4"
      top: "pool4"
      pooling_param {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 2
        stride: 2
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv5"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "pool4"
      top: "conv5"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
        decay_mult: 1.0
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
        decay_mult: 0.0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0.0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "relu5"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv5"
      top: "conv5"
    }
    layer {
      name: "pool5"
      type: "Pooling"
      bottom: "conv5"
      top: "pool5"
      pooling_param {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 2
        stride: 2
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv6"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "pool5"
      top: "conv6"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1.0
        decay_mult: 1.0
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2.0
        decay_mult: 0.0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 64
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0.0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "relu6"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv6"
      top: "conv6"
    }
    layer {
      name: "pool6"
      type: "Pooling"
      bottom: "conv6"
      top: "pool6"
      pooling_param {
        pool: MAX
        kernel_size: 2
        stride: 2
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not *need* a pre-trained model. Actually, when you are developing your own, custom architecture, you cannot even get a pre-trained model.

1200 images is not much, but without any other information, one cannot tell if it is enough or not. Maybe your problem is simple, your network small and the dataset will be enough. Maybe your problem is tough and even 10<sup>9</sup> images would not be enough. There is no simple answer to that.

Also, there is no simple answer to which of the two options will be better. I would start training from scratch, using augmented dataset. Ideally, generate the augmented versions on the fly rather than creating a fixed amount (e.g. 18) from each image. If you observe poor performance, pre-train on VOC and then fine-tune on your own data (but still use augmentation). This is the only way to compare which is better.

As final remarks, I would recommend [this article](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607) summarizing some good tips for neural network development and debugging; and [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn) focused on learning problems.

Comment: Yes thanks. my classification is only two classes classification only.